# Pydev Eclipse console does not support curses.setupterm

Tags: console, pydev, curses

I cannot run a script in Eclipse that works perfectly in a terminal.
It seems that Eclipse console cannot support some functions. I am looking for a workaround to be able to debug the script using Pydev.
Is it possible to set PyDev to use for example /usr/bin/gnome-terminal instead of the Eclipse native console ? 
Otherwise it there a way to define a wrapper as a python interpreter for PyDev that will launch an terminal external to Eclipse (I've tried but failed on that).

Thank you
Nga

Answer (score 0):

Right now, curses-based apps really don't run well inside Eclipse/PyDev, so, you must really launch it externally. To debug you can use the remote debugger: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html

If you use Aptana Studio, there's a terminal view which should emulate a terminal better... try running python (i.e.: running your program) from inside that view. If it does work properly there, maybe I could check a way to better integrate there and launch directly in that view.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have finally defined kind of a wrapper as a bash script calling python in a xterm. Pydev is checking some configuration by calling eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_2.4.0.2012020116/PySrc/interpreterInfo.py so the script first echo the format expected by PyDev.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply. I have finally defined kind of a wrapper as a bash script calling python in a xterm. Pydev is checking some configuration by calling eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_2.4.0.2012020116/PySrc/interpreterInfo.py so the script first echo the format expected by PyDev. here is the script "

```
#!/bin/bash
# dummy return for Eclipse Pydev - respect interpreter info format
echo "EXECUTABLE:/home/user/python_custom/python_xterm|
|/home/user/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_2.4.0.2012020116/PySrc
|/usr/lib/python2.5
|/usr/lib/python2.5/plat-linux2
|/usr/lib/python2.5/lib-tk
|/usr/lib/python2.5/lib-dynload
|/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages
|/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages
|/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Numeric
|/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/PIL
|/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gst-0.10
|/var/lib/python-support/python2.5
|/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0
|/var/lib/python-support/python2.5/gtk-2.0
|/var/lib/python-support/python2.5/HTMLgen
|/var/lib/python-support/python2.5/pyinotify
|/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/wx-2.6-gtk2-unicode
|/usr/lib/site-python
@
$
|__builtin__
|__main__
|_ast
|_codecs
|_sre
|_symtable
|_types
|errno
|exceptions
|gc
|imp
|marshal
|posix
|pwd
|signal
|sys
|thread
|xxsubtype
|zipimport
"
# activate scrollbar -sb with 6000 lines
# allow logging -l with filename log_$NOW
xterm -g 150x100+0+0 -sb -sl 6000 -si -hold -e "python $*"
```

that does the job, and I can use Pydev and its debugger